# Combining 2 worksheet_change events for pivot filters

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to run multiple worksheet change events for filtering a number of pivot tables on a seperate sheet  to where the pivot tables are, but I don't know how to combine the two macros. Both macros work on a standalone basis. Can anyone show me how to combine them? Macro 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xPTable As PivotTable
Dim xPFile As PivotField
Dim xStr As String
Dim Pvt As String

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each xPTable In Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables

    Pvt = xPTable.Name

    If Pvt = "PivotTable2" Or Pvt = "PivotTable4" Or Pvt = "PivotTable5" Or Pvt = "PivotTable6" Then

        Set xPTable = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables(Pvt)
        Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("Code")
        xStr = Target.Text
        xPFile.ClearAllFilters
        xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr

    Else
    End If

Next xPTable

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Macro 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xPTable As PivotTable
Dim xPFile As PivotField
Dim xStr As String
Dim Pvt As String

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, Range("C11:C12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each xPTable In Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables

    Pvt = xPTable.Name

    If Pvt = "PivotTable1" Or Pvt = "PivotTable3" Then

        Set xPTable = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables(Pvt)
        Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("Ref")
        xStr = Target.Text
        xPFile.ClearAllFilters
        xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr

    Else
    End If

Next xPTable

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `Worksheet_Change` events to simply call other macros.

Note that this change event can only be called from the sheet that you have the macro stored which means you may need to know the sheet the cell was changed on if you plan to call macros to operate on a different sheet. You can find the sheet that had the change using `Target.Parent.Name`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Macro1 Target
    Macro2 Target

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Macro1(Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Rest of your code here for this change event

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Macro2(Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("C11:C12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Rest of your code here for this change event

End Sub
```